# Add additional data to JQuery FileUpload on Upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using this mini version of the JQuery file uploader:

https://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form

However, when someone clicks the upload button, I need them to be able to enter a Title for the upload.

I have it working currently on Chrome desktop and iPhone safari, but it doesn't work on iPhone chrome for some reason, so maybe there is something I am doing wrong?

This is the fileupload JQuery:

```
      // Initialize the jQuery File Upload plugin
      $('#upload').fileupload({

          // This element will accept file drag/drop uploading
          dropZone: $('#drop'),
    maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
          // This function is called when a file is added to the queue;
          // either via the browse button, or via drag/drop:
          add: function (e, data) {

//This prompts the user to enter a title.
data.files[0].filetitle = window.prompt("Enter a Name for This Job", data.files[0].name);

              var tpl = $('<li class="working"><input type="text" value="0" data-width="48" data-height="48"'+
                  ' data-fgColor="#0788a5" data-readOnly="1" data-bgColor="#3e4043" /><p></p><span></span></li>');

              // Append the file name and file size
              tpl.find('p').text(data.files[0].name)
                           .append('<i>' + formatFileSize(data.files[0].size) + '</i>');

              // Add the HTML to the UL element
              data.context = tpl.appendTo(ul);

              // Initialize the knob plugin
              tpl.find('input').knob();

              // Listen for clicks on the cancel icon
              tpl.find('span').click(function(){

                  if(tpl.hasClass('working')){
                      jqXHR.abort();
                  }

                  tpl.fadeOut(function(){
                      tpl.remove();
                  });

              });

              // This adds the title to the form for submission as well as creates the action.
               data.formData = {action : 'process_uploads',filetitle: data.files[0].filetitle};


              var jqXHR = data.submit();
          },
```

The lines I have added are first this one to prompt the end-user to enter their title:

```
data.files[0].filetitle = window.prompt("Enter a Name for This Job", data.files[0].name);
```

And this one to add the entered text to the submitted form:

```
data.formData = {action : 'process_uploads',filetitle: data.files[0].filetitle};
```

Could there be a way around this that would work on mobile Chrome or is there something else wrong here?